# NetBeans or Eclipse. Which IDE should I use first?

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio, netbeans, ide

I've been creating Java programs in a text editor for more than a year and now I want to switch to any IDE for creating Java applications. May I know which IDE should I use first? Eclipse or NetBeans? Which is more preferable for a starter?

I've also done a little work in Visual Studio for creating C# applications. Will working on any IDE gonna be helpful for me?

Comment: Eclipse. Or NetBeans. It really doesn't matter. I would personally go for Eclipse since that seems to have a vastly larger number of tools for it. Whether that's good for a beginner is debatable. But since this is a subjective question, I have to vote to close, sorry.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839908/netbeans-or-eclipse-for-java-development

Comment: Could these type of questions be rephrased as to adhere to SO rules instead of being closed?  I find them kind of useful despite their subjective nature.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've always liked NetBeans for it's simplicity, however I use Eclipse as it has an official plugin for Android, provided by Google.  Eclipse is very good but also somewhat complicated - I've used it for years and probably don't know what 60% of the settings or features even do.

So stick to NetBeans, unless you're doing Android development.

Comment: So what do you recommend if someone works with both desktop application and android as well? I use netbeans for php and javascript. Should I switch to eclipse if I want to learn java?

Comment: @partho I think you could still use NetBeans for both.  However there is no reason to use the same IDE for both PHP and Java/Android development.

Comment: Right. But actually I use sublime text for PHP,Javascript. Thank you for your kind information.

Comment: For Android development, google is providing Android Studio (developed on intelliJ) now. Which is lot better and simpler.

Answer (score 25):

Eclipse is definitely closer to the text editor environment you're used to, while NetBeans is more geared towards interface development.

A stock installation of Eclipse is extremely lightweight relative to NetBeans. NetBeans is probably closer to Visual Studio. It depends on what kind of environment you prefer to work in.

If you enjoyed and preferred text editor coding, I'd go with Eclipse. If you preferred Visual Studio-style environments, I'd go with NetBeans.

If your computer is old, I'd go with Eclipse as well.

Comment: *If your computer is old, I'd go with Eclipse.* NetBeans actually seems lighter in some respects.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse is heavily developed by third parties (google, adobe), netBeans by oracle, so while doing some job with java i felt netBeans to be more "native" for java. Although i do most of the programming in other languages so i use eclipse, since you can bend it to any direction you want.
So, all in all, if you're planing just program in java and have done something with visual studio - use netbeans

Comment: IBM may have written a line or two of Eclipse as well...

Comment: Thanks for correction. The point yet remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

When I was learning Java they had us using [jGRASP](http://www.jgrasp.org/), then had us using Netbeans. Netbeans and Eclipse are very similar if you are just starting.

This is the IDE I use http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans is more to Visual Studio, if you are working on GUI app or Jasper reports, Netbeans is also your choice. In all other cases - Eclipse. Eclipse has much more plug-ins, integrated with server-side environment and easier customizable